# clickonce nightmare System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException

Tags: vb.net

anyone know how to fix this? this is what i get when i try to run setup.exe

PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 5.1.2600.196608 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 2.0.50727.3053
    System.Deployment.dll       : 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    mscorwks.dll            : 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    dfdll.dll           : 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    dfshim.dll          : 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/PGarcia.BMRA/Desktop/Intol%20Prog/WindowsApplication1.application

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : WindowsApplication1.application, Version=1.0.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9ac82ee8eb508b4, processorArchitecture=msil

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Documents and Settings\PGarcia.BMRA\Desktop\Intol Prog\WindowsApplication1.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading file:///C:/Documents and Settings/PGarcia.BMRA/Desktop/Intol Prog/Application Files/WindowsApplication1_1_0_0_3/WindowsApplication1.exe.manifest did not succeed.
        + Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Documents and Settings\PGarcia.BMRA\Desktop\Intol Prog\Application Files\WindowsApplication1_1_0_0_3\WindowsApplication1.exe.manifest'.
        + Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Documents and Settings\PGarcia.BMRA\Desktop\Intol Prog\Application Files\WindowsApplication1_1_0_0_3\WindowsApplication1.exe.manifest'.
        + Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Documents and Settings\PGarcia.BMRA\Desktop\Intol Prog\Application Files\WindowsApplication1_1_0_0_3\WindowsApplication1.exe.manifest'.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [6/9/2009 11:26:55 AM] : Activation of C:\Documents and Settings\PGarcia.BMRA\Desktop\Intol Prog\WindowsApplication1.application has started.
    * [6/9/2009 11:26:56 AM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [6/9/2009 11:26:56 AM] : Installation of the application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [6/9/2009 11:26:56 AM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading file:///C:/Documents and Settings/PGarcia.BMRA/Desktop/Intol Prog/Application Files/WindowsApplication1_1_0_0_3/WindowsApplication1.exe.manifest did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifest(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ManifestType manifestType, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Documents and Settings\PGarcia.BMRA\Desktop\Intol Prog\Application Files\WindowsApplication1_1_0_0_3\WindowsApplication1.exe.manifest'.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Documents and Settings\PGarcia.BMRA\Desktop\Intol Prog\Application Files\WindowsApplication1_1_0_0_3\WindowsApplication1.exe.manifest'.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
        - Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Documents and Settings\PGarcia.BMRA\Desktop\Intol Prog\Application Files\WindowsApplication1_1_0_0_3\WindowsApplication1.exe.manifest'.
        - Source: mscorlib
        - Stack trace:
            at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
            at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
            at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
            at System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async)
            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had this same problem embedded in our ClickOnce deployment of [Qiqqa.com][1].  I suspect it has to do with the "MIME Type sniffing" that IE does when it gets an application/octet-stream - I guess to protect the user from malicious stuff.

Anyway, to solve the problem, we changed the mime type of our .deploy files to be text/plain - obviously not ideal, but at the same time, I don't know a scenario where we might have a .deploy file on our server that a user would browse to outside ClickOnce.

Problem solved.

Cheers,

Jimme

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the exact cause of the problem, but the exception had this:

> Could not find a part of the path
>   'C:\Documents and
>   Settings\PGarcia.BMRA\Desktop\Intol
>   Prog\Application
>   Files\WindowsApplication1_1_0_0_3\WindowsApplication1.exe.manifest

So that may be the best place to start troubleshooting.

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

i was running two sessions of the installer at the same time for some reason

Comment: can you provide details on that? How can one run "two sessions of the installer" at the same time?