# Published Setup Error: Cannot start application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, installation

I built an speech application using C#, Visual Studio 2010 Professional. App is using speech.dll. After completing it, I simply clicked `Build->Publish` in IDE. It generated the setup. However, as soon as I gave it to the client, he said he said the setup says it can not install because of an error. I installed the application into another computer of mine and I got the same error. The setup is not working! The following is the error

[image]

The details of the error is below:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7600.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.17929
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/yohan/Downloads/setup/Voice%20Software.application

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Users\yohan\Downloads\setup\Voice Software.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading file:///C:/Users/yohan/Downloads/setup/Voice Software.application did not succeed.
        + Could not find file 'C:\Users\yohan\Downloads\setup\Voice Software.application'.
        + Could not find file 'C:\Users\yohan\Downloads\setup\Voice Software.application'.
        + Could not find file 'C:\Users\yohan\Downloads\setup\Voice Software.application'.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [04-Jun-13 11:13:32 AM] : Activation of C:\Users\yohan\Downloads\setup\Voice Software.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [04-Jun-13 11:13:37 AM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading file:///C:/Users/yohan/Downloads/setup/Voice Software.application did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - Could not find file 'C:\Users\yohan\Downloads\setup\Voice Software.application'.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - Could not find file 'C:\Users\yohan\Downloads\setup\Voice Software.application'.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.IO.FileNotFoundException
        - Could not find file 'C:\Users\yohan\Downloads\setup\Voice Software.application'.
        - Source: mscorlib
        - Stack trace:
            at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
            at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
            at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
            at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean useAsync)
            at System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async)
            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

This setup only works fine in the machine where the application is built. It do not need to download anything! Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to set the `codebase` attribute in `/asmv1:assembly/asmv2:deployment/asmv2:deploymentProvider` correctly. This is called the "Update location" in Visual Studio's dialogs.

See the MSDN for [more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7050f3w.aspx).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082410/clickonce-setup-exe-fails-but-the-application-file-works-fine-when-using-a-wind) for a similar problem, with a much more in-depth answer.