# Clickonce installation fails to download

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I had made a Clickonce deployemnt to my application set the installation folder and publishing folder the same that is a network share  and then it work perfect for my development machine
Then when I went to on client machine opened the network share and I tried to install the application using that setup file i got tht message like below

[image]

And in details  Iam getting the below message

```
LATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.586
System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.586 (RTMLDR.030319-5800)
dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
dfshim.dll          : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file://it-dept/Project/mycutorderlast/CutorderFresh.application
    Deployment Provider url     : http://it-dept/CutorderFresh/CutorderFresh.application

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of \\it-dept\Project\mycutorderlast\CutorderFresh.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading http://it-dept/CutorderFresh/CutorderFresh.application did not succeed.
        + The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [08/10/2013 14:03:25] : Activation of \\it-dept\Project\mycutorderlast\CutorderFresh.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [08/10/2013 14:03:30] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading http://it-dept/CutorderFresh/CutorderFresh.application did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifest(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ManifestType manifestType, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirect(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.FollowDeploymentProviderUri(SubscriptionStore subStore, AssemblyManifest& deployment, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Can anyone suggest what was the issue As Iam using clickonce for the first time

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082410/clickonce-setup-exe-fails-but-the-application-file-works-fine-when-using-a-wind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check values of 'Publish Location' or 'Installation URL' on Publish tab of properties. According to your current settings, you should have published files accessible by this path: `http://it-dept/CutorderFresh/CutorderFresh.application` and it looks like they're not available by this path.

[Here you can read how to set proper 'Publish Location' and 'Installation URL' values](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ed62d923-4340-4f3c-b883-42da38985a54/what-is-the-difference-between-the-publishing-folder-location-and-the-installation-folder-url?forum=winformssetup)

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and it was driving me mad.  I knew I had the proper permissions set up on the network's shared folder.  I couldn't even install my application from my own machine via the network share.  After searching long and hard for an answer I figured it out myself.

On the Publish tab of properties I only filled in the "Publishing Folder Location" with:

\servername\share\Application Folder

I left the "Installation Folder URL" section blank.

Somehow a field in the "Application Updates" section (via clicking "Updates" button on Publish tab) got filled in with a different value than what my network share was.  Not sure if I did this myself or if it was set by default.  I cleared out the "Update Location (if different than the publish location)" field and that fixed this issue for me.  Here is a screen shot of where I changed the field:

I would post a screen shot of the form that was causing me trouble but for some reason I need 10 reputation points to post a picture.

Comment: After I blanked the field I had to check "The application should check for update" then uncheck it to take it into account.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem like yours.

I don't know that "**Publishing Folder Location**" of my application (below "formtest" App.) is different from "Installation Folder URL".

In fact, two folders of former WEB server for click once deployment were not different. So, I was confused after WEB server was changed.

1. Publishing Folder Location: \12.39.526.272\root\formtest\
2. Installation Folder URL: http://12.39.526.272:8080/formtest/
3. Application Updates section   "Update Location (if different than the publish location)" field : http://12.39.526.272:8080/formtest/

I'm so sorry My native language is not English.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but resolved it a different way.  Somehow I had accidentially unchecked something in the Options.

On the Publish tab, select "Options".  Under Deployment, make sure "Use .deploy file extension" is checked.  Once I checked that and republished, the error went away.